# How do you send a message to the client when PHP form submission download fails

Tags: javascript, php, download

My app has the ability to request and download a multitude of different files and types from the database.

The way I'm currently doing this is with a hidden form input that will submit the request to server which then does the processing and downloads the file. The code for that looks like this:

```
       var action = '/download/downloader.php?actionname&filename=' + downloadfilename;
        
        var A = document.createElement("div");
        A.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(A);
        var formKey = 'someid';
        A.innerHTML = '<form id="' + formKey + '" method="post" action="' + action + '" accept-charset="utf-8"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"' + target + '><input type="hidden" name="segmentno" id="segmentno"/> </form>';
        document.getElementById(formKey).submit();
        A.parentNode.removeChild(A);
```

The PHP side for downloading an XML file will look something like this (all the cases set the output data and headers accordingly)

```
// $a is the data from the database
        $xmlEncode = new XMLEncode();
        $xmlstring =  $xmlEncode->XML_SerializeData($a);
        $xmlstring = str_replace('&apos;', '&apos;&apos;', $xmlstring);
    
        header("Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=". $this->sFileName .".xml");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

        exit($xmlstring);
```

This works great when there is no pre-processing required (permission checks, valid key checks, etc...)

However, if I have some server-side pre-processing to do prior to this portion, and it fails, I need a way to send a message back to the front end.

I know with what I have, it will not work. My only thought is that I will need to do the pre-processing in a separate AJAX call and then if it's successful, run the actual download but that isn't ideal. Some other solutions I've looked into include using fetch to get the data back and then potentially using a library to download the blob data but again, I'm not sure if I can tell whether or not it was actually a successful server request or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You're submitting a form. So the page will post back. If the validation fails, return some HTML (containing the feedback) instead of the file data, and don't set any of the headers. It should then show some feedback on the screen.

Comment: Does the task server side require a long time, say minutes? The php default ini max connection time is set by default to 30s. But it's not great to leave the client browser hanging, instead you can use js. A simple call to your server, sent from the client every 10s or something. When the server answer ok, kill the loop, and show the succeed message. In a modern way, this is a job for websockets.

Comment: @NVRM I agree this is likely a case for websockets.

Comment: @ADyson It's not redirecting the page so there is no way to capture the server response in pure javascript that I am aware of without AJAX which again leads to the last paragraph in my question. Yes, if it was a form request that redirects the page then it would be possible to just send the error in the page back

Comment: You can also use http status code. From php you set a different header, depending the state. Example use `206` when the upload and processing fail, and `200` when everything is alright. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#206 Just an idea. I would still go for a 10s verification loop from the client browser. You have to implement a verification handpoint, use unique tokens.

Comment: " It's not redirecting the page"...only because you've set headers which tell the browser to treat the response as a file download instead. And/or possibly because you've told it to submit to a new browser window? (I can't see the contents of your `target` variable.) But that was my point - if you _don't_ set those headers in the case of an error, then you should be able to echo some HTML into the response just using PHP and it will be displayed - either on the main page, or in your separate window, depending on the form's target. No Javascript required for that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is creating an iFrame for the download and the form will target it.

Now my download class will return an output array to the download endpoint where I can check if it passed the pre process, process, and post processing. If it did not succeed, I set the headers to back to text/html and inject a line of JS into the iFrame window where I can then target the parent window and call my error function with the message passed from the output data.

My PHP download endpoint:

```
if (!$aOutput['success']){
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline");
    exit('<script type="text/javascript">if (window.parent.Footer) {window.parent.Footer._download.error(\''. $aOutput['data'] .'\') } else { window.parent.w360.error(\'' . $aOutput['data'] . '\', \'Download Failed\')}</script>');
}
```